# Unspecified constant expression values and ODR

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Consider this program in three files:

```
// a.h

#include<iostream>

constexpr auto f() {
    int i = 0;
    auto l1 = [](int& j) { return ++j; };
    auto l2 = [](int& j) { return j*=2; };
    return l1(i) + l2(i);
}

template<auto V> struct constant {};

inline auto g() {
    constexpr auto x = f();
    std::ios_base::Init init; // Avoid possible initialization order issues
    std::cout << x;
    return constant<x>{};
}

static auto x = g();
inline auto y = g();
```

```
// a.cpp

#include "a.h"
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "a.h"

int main() {
}
```

with `a.cpp` and `main.cpp` compiled as translation units. I think the definition of `g` should be an ODR violation, because `f()` may evaluate to either `1` or `3`, thereby changing the return type of `g()` and what it will output to `std::cout`.

However, all names in the definition will, after name lookup and overload resolution, refer to the same entities in each translation unit that includes `a.h`, so I don't see which of the ODR requirements is violated.

Does the program violate the one-definition-rule. If yes, which part exactly is violated?

Comment: Naively, while the return value of `f()` is unspecified, it's unlikely to change between evaluations by the same compiler. It's not like the compiler tosses a coin and decides to evaluate it as `1` sometimes and as `3` other times.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I agree that it is unlikely to cause issues in practice, although maybe one could image libraries compiled with different compiler minor versions that modify the evaluation order decision, since that shouldn't normally be ABI breaking or anything. In any case such code should in practice probably be considered a bug anyway, since one doesn't want functions with unspecified output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-overloadable non-inline function definitions in different translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402439/non-overloadable-non-inline-function-definitions-in-different-translation-units)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I would say that it might depend of call place: With inlining, some order might be "better" than other so resulting in different result. Or constexpr evaluation vs runtime evaluation.

Comment: @Jarod42 Here, it's got to be compile-time evaluation, or the problem fails to arise. It's OK that `cout << f()` could print different values at runtime - that's not an ODR violation. The question is, could `constant<f()>` represent different types at compile time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I understand your first comment in general case, not in constexpr context  (exclusively).

Comment: I think any use of FP has the same issues.

Comment: This might be undefined behavior, because `l1` and `l2` are unsequenced and both have side effects on `i`.

Comment: @sigma They're not unsequenced. They're indeterminately sequenced. Function bodies can't be interleaved on a single thread.

Comment: @BrianBi You're right, I had them mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

[basic.def.odr]/6 states:

> [...] If the definitions of `D` satisfy all these requirements, then the behavior is as if there were a single definition of `D`. [...]

The entire program must behave as if there's only one copy of `g`. That implies that when the two translation units are compiled separately, the implementation (one way or another) must ensure that it doesn't do anything that would make the two copies of `g` not interchangeable with each other, such as computing two different values for `f()`. In any *other* situation, the implementation is allowed to evaluate `f()` to 1 in some invocations and to 3 in others (even though it's unlikely that a real implementation would do that), but in this particular situation, it must ensure that both invocations return the same value.

Comment: _If the definitions of `D` satisfy all these requirements_ Maybe there is no problem with this particular example, but can't we add `x` value dependent partial specializations so that https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#13.9 requirement becomes a problem?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm not sure what you mean, can you provide a godbolt link?

Comment: smth. like this https://godbolt.org/z/oTPn68Tf8

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I suppose you're right, that does look like a problematic case. We should fix this by giving constant evaluation a well-defined order of evaluation - something I also advocate for other reasons.